# Converting VB.net replace to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want convert this VB.net snippet to C#

```
sURL = Replace(sURL,"%F9","%C3%B9",,,CompareMethod.Text)
```

Which one of these is better?

```
sURL = Strings.Replace(sURL,"%F3","%C3%B3", 1, -1, CompareMethod.Text);
sURL = Regex.Replace(sURL,"%FA","%C3%BA",CompareMethod.Text);
```

Comment: `Strings.Replace` (plural), or `String.Replace`?

Comment: Generally `Regex` is a bit more expensive than methods on `String` so go with `String.Replace()` unless you are actually going to do `Regex`.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: The "Strings.Replace" referred to is a reference to the method in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace (the op is considering this as an option).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Regex replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used for [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). Here you haven't regular expression, so it's better to use usual replace:

```
sURL = sURL.Replace("%F3","%C3%B3");
```

Answer (score 2):

I simple `String.Replace` will be more efficient than `Regex.Replace` when you are doing a straightforward text-replace.  If you don't need any of the features of `Regex`, it's best not to use it.